# Can this conflict between `biblatex` and redefining the `\section` command be solved?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, sectioning, incompatibility, block

I am making a poster with the `beamer` class and the `beamerposter` package and I want to use enumerated blocks. They way I'm doing it is by defining a `sectionblock` environment as follows:

```
\newenvironment<>{sectionblock}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}%
  \begin{block}#2{\thesection.~#1}}{\end{block}}
```

But since I will not use the `\section` command for anything else, I think it would be cool to remove it as a command and transform it into an environment defined as `sectionblock`. (Especially because I'm making a `cls` file that I want to share.)

I have seen that it is perfectly possible to do this. However, a conflict with the `biblatex` package arises even with a code as simple as this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\renewenvironment<>{section}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}%
    \begin{block}#2{\thesection.~#1}}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{derksen1993sins}

\begin{section}{Descartes}
    Cogito ergo sum.
\end{section}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When I execute this code, it returns the following error messages:

```
line 18: You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.
line 18: Missing } inserted.
line 19: Improper \prevdepth. \end{document}
line 19: Missing } inserted. \end{document}
line 19: \begin{beamercolorbox} on input line 17 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
line 17: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available(Font) Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/sc' tried instead
```

Here is the [log file](https://justpaste.it/51xt0).

And here is the outcome:

[image: Outcome PDF]

Is there a straightforward way to solve this conflict or do I have to make do with my original `sectionblock`? I would accept as answer "This is so unnecessarily complicated that you should better use your `sectionblock`" if some explanation is given about the nature of the conflict.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: biblatex is probably using `\section` to make the headline for the bibliography. This is usually a macro that can be redefined, see the `biblatex` manual. Though, overloading section like this may confuse potential users. Also may I ask why you are not basing this on the `tcolorbox` poster features instead of beamer, tcolorbox seems a lot more powerfull.

Comment: Thanks, @daleif. I'm not using `tcolorbox` mainly because I don't know it. Also, `beamer` would make it easy for me to go from making my slides to making my poster and vice versa. (I also like the fact that it has several themes and colour themes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to redefine the heading command - at least the default one, perhaps more if you expect that others are used too.

On the whole I don't think that it is a great idea to redefine section - it is a quite standard command and people expect it to behave in a certain way.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewenvironment<>{section}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}%
    \begin{block}#2{\thesection.~#1}}{\end{block}}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{Some heading code for the bibliography}    
\begin{document}

\nocite{doody}

\begin{section}{Descartes}
    Cogito ergo sum.
\end{section}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @UlrikeFischer. For the record, I have tested your answer in the context of a more complex document and it still has some problems. I think this is a good reason not redefining the `\section` command. (No matter how cool I think that might be.)